# Different view in storyboard

Tags: xcode, layout, storyboard

I am having little trouble with view in storyboard. In image 1 I want lines are displayed but in image 2 there are no lines. How to turn on those line for image 2. Thanks

Image 1: [image: Image 1]

Image 2: [image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose Editor > Canvas > Show Layout Rectangles.

Comment: Thanks, Correct answer